# Github credentials not working on Sourcetree

Tags: github, fatal-error, atlassian-sourcetree

I used Sourcetree with Github as my remote repo base. I was able to connect and fetch the code from the Github repo but due to some issue has to restart the sourcetree. And now the credentials donot work. I tried the suggestions like setting the PAT and using it instead of password for GIT basic authentication. But it has not worked. If I do any FETCH or PULL, it asks for GITHUB credentials and when I use the Username/password i use to log into GIthub (it works in Github) but when i use same in Sourcetree to connect to github, it doesnt work. And I get this error - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2wCa.png)

I can login into sourcetree with my bitbucket account but for some reason this fetches the commits that were done about an year ago on a different branch.
Any help/advice on what I could do to resolve this please.

Comment: This really seems like a support issue, not a programming question (and not something that can be answered here).

Comment: @DavidMakogon - According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, the scope of stackoverflow includes "software tools commonly used by programmers".  `Sourcetree` is definitely a tool commonly used by programmers.  The fact it has its own tag suggests that questions about how to use it are on-topic.